# How to install specific versions of H2O

Tags: python, h2o

I need to install an older version of H2O because model loading doesn't work even if the versions are just one apart (3.26.0.2 vs. 3.26.0.3). I'm struggling to find a page from which I can find the download links. Why doesn't it exist? All software have an archive or older versions page for this. I also tried playing with the link to current version but no luck as it doesn't have a pattern you could guess.
So how can I install H2O 3.26.0.2 in Python (pip)?

Looked all over the web and documentation

`model = h2o.load_model("H2O.model_name.zip")`

````
  Error: Found version 3.26.0.2, but running version 3.26.0.3
  Request: POST /99/Models.bin/
    data: {'dir': 'H2O.model_name.zip'}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Changes.md`](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md) file is the easiest place to look for links to where you can download every version.  Just search for the version you want (e.g. "3.26.0.2") and you will see the URL there.

Click on the link and it will bring you to the [download page for that version](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yau/2/index.html) and you can click on the "Install in Python" tab which will show some code like this that you can copy/paste into your terminal:

```
# The following command removes the H2O module for Python.
pip uninstall h2o

# Next, use pip to install this version of the H2O Python module.
pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yau/2/Python/h2o-3.26.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The URLs are "predictable" but you have to know the name of the release as well as the version number to correctly guess the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing h2o via pip, go to [Release History page in the PyPi page for H2O](https://pypi.org/project/h2o/#history). Look for the specific version you need and install that version based on the command provided over there. It should be similar to the following command.

```
pip install h2o==3.26.0.2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).