# Get specific h2o version in R

Tags: r, h2o

I am aware that a similar question has been posted in the context of Python: [How to install specific versions of H2O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749892/how-to-install-specific-versions-of-h2o)

However, I need to find the relevant link for the R releases. I am currently trying to use an h2o model which I doesn't work because of conflicting releases. How can I get a previous version of h2o, namely 3.30.0.1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing older version of R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package)

Answer (score 1):

I'll reframe the answer I wrote for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749967/5451344), for R.  It's the same process:

The [`Changes.md`](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md) file is the easiest place to look for links to where you can download every version.  Just search for the version you want (e.g. "3.30.0.1") and you [will see](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md#zahradnik-33001---432020) the URL there.

Click on the link and it will bring you to the [download page for that version (e.g. 3.30.0.1)](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zahradnik/1/index.html) and you can click on the "Install in R" tab which will show some code like this that you can copy/paste into your terminal:

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload = TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type = "source", repos = "http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zahradnik/1/R")
```

The URLs are "predictable" but you have to know the name of the release as well as the version number to correctly guess the URL.

Comment: Thank you! I found that amazonaws link but on first glance thought it wasn't useful due to it not having a version number for the release. Turns out for the R packages they don't give the release number but the working name.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit confusing with the version number and version name, so the only way to get all the info is to look in Changes.md.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use the provided `install_version()` function of the devtools package to install the version you need. For instance:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("h2o", version = "3.30.0.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Caveat: This only works for versions that were released to CRAN.  Not all H2O versions are released to CRAN (major versions are, but not all minor versions are).